# Problem with implementing Brzozowski's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, automata, finite-automata

I've been trying to implement Brzozowski's algorithm but I've just discovered that it creates suboptimal automata for a certain class of inputs, having one more state than what is really needed in the result. I can show it on a trivial automaton:

```
   a b           a   b           a b            a     b            a b
>0 0 1  rev  *0 0,2  -   det  >0 - 1  rev  *0   -     -    det  >0 1 2
 1 1 2  -->   1  1   0   -->   1 2 5  -->   1   -    0,4   -->   1 1 2
*2 0 2       >2  -  1,2        2 2 3        2  1,2    -          2 2 3
                              *3 4 -        3   -     2         *3 1 3
                              *4 4 1        4  3,4    -          
                              *5 5 5        5   5    1,5         
                                           >6 3,4,5 1,2,5
```

Here *rev* is the edge reversal part, where I'd already removed the transitions on epsilon, and *det* is determinization through powerset construction, creating new states as soon as it discovers them, recursively.

The problem here is this: once I add the extra state to make up for the three different start states after the first edge reversal and powerset construction, nothing ever returns to that state and thus I can't get rid of it later for being equivalent to the original start state.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an excellent question!

The reverting step in Brzozowski's Algorithm does not introduce a new virtual starting state that leads to the old accepting states via $\varepsilon$-transitions. Instead it allows multiple starting states, which is no big problem, if you construct the product-automaton anyway right after the reversion.

Conceptually, it is the easiest to consider reverting and determinization as one single step. If your DEA is $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$, then define as the reverted DEA  $ M^R=(Q^R,\Sigma,\delta^R,q_0^R,F^R)$ as follows:

- $Q^R=\mathcal{P}(Q)$,
- $q_0^R=F$,
- $F^R=\{ P\subseteq Q \mid q_0\in P\}$,
- $\delta^R(P,a):=\{ p\in Q \mid \delta(p,a)\in P\}$.

(You might want to ignore states that are not reachable.)

Brzozowski's Theorem states that $(M^R)^R$ is a minimal DEA accepting $L(M)$.

For further reading I suggest [Elements of Automata Theory by Sakarovitch](http://www.cambridge.org/de/knowledge/isbn/item2715193/) pages 116-117.