# How to find the minimum number of states of a deterministic finite automaton accepting a given language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

Let

1. $L$ be a language over $\Sigma$. And $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ is a set of input alphabets.
2. $L = \{ w \mid w \in \Sigma^*, \text{ where $w$ is a string with numbers of 0s divisible by 3 and number of 1s divisible by 5}\}$.

What will be the minimum numbers of states in the DFA accepting $L$?

My approach is to create a grid like this:

[image]

I am getting 5 x 3 = 15 states.

How can I apply Myhill Nerode theorem to solve this kind of problems?
I don't understand this theorem at all.

Comment: Please read [the wikipedia article on DFA minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) or relevant chapters of some textbooks for general algorithms that minimize the number of states of a DFA.

Comment: The empty string satisfies the condition but is not recognised by your DFA. Remember that 0 is a multiple of 3 (and of 5); the empty string is not the only valid string not recognised. Fixing that will produce a smaller automaton.

Comment: @rici yeah I missed that. The start state will also be an accepting state. What are the other valid strings it does not recognises.

Comment: Any string with no 0s or no 1s

Comment: Wow I did not saw that. Lets number the states with its rows and cols. Then I can fix it by making with transitions $\delta$(00,0) = 51 and $\delta$(00,1) = 13

Comment: The minimal number of states for your language is 15. See if you can find a DFA with that number of states.

Comment: Hi, @YuvalFilmus thanks for the edit. Yes, I am able to create a DFA with 15 states. The answer of D.W  [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/minimum-number-of-states-in-dfa-for-the-given-language) talks about Myhill Nerode theorem. I don't understand the approach. Can anyone please make me understand?

Comment: If you're familiar with Myhill-Nerode theory, you can come up with the proof yourself. Otherwise, get yourself familiar with Myhill-Nerode theory.